# .Net Framework RegFree COM Manifest Match error

Tags: regfreecom

I'm trying to set up RegFree COM on a .Net Framework (4.8) library that is exposed to COM.

I've followed the instructions contained in:

[Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/configure-net-framework-based-com-components-for-reg)

I've set up things in the way described. When it comes time to activate COM object CreateInstance returns '0x80131040 The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference'.

I created the manifests for both client and component and made sure the component manifest was embedded as a resource in the component. Here is the component manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" version="1.0.0.0" name="RegFreeCOMDemoFramework" processorArchitecture="msil"/>
    <clrClass clsid="{99A185F7-E91F-4988-BB4C-909139CCEC63}"
        progid="RegFreeCOMDemoFramework.FrameworkClass"
        threadingModel="Both"
        name="RegFreeCOMDemoFramework.RegFreeCOMDemoFramework"/>
    <file name="RegFreeCOMDemoFramework.dll"/>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false">
                </requestedExecutionLevel>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

I also created a client manifest as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" version="1.0.0.0" name="RegFreeCOMDemo_Driver" processorArchitecture="msil"/>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" version="1.0.0.0" name="RegFreeCOMDemoFramework" processorArchitecture="msil"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
</assembly>
```

And then I added an exe.config file for the client executable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

So it seems I'm missing some notion about what it means for manifests to "match".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got it to work.

The processorArchitecture attribute needed to be "amd64".

Comment: What computer O/S and other details are you using?

Comment: Windows 11, .Net Framework 4.8, 143 visual studio build tools

Comment: What kind of PC that it needs to be AMD64?

Comment: I built the assembly for x64 specifically, so I suspect that's why. I think 'msil' corresponds to 'Any CPU' but that's not how I built it.